# Video Player for Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, html, video, mediaelement.js, atk4

I'm looking for an add-on implementing a basic video player for Agile Toolkit. Does anyone have anything to contribute? Here is the code I'd expect to write to use it:

```
$player = $video->add('VideoPlayer_YouTube');
$player->setSource($url);
```

But should also be capable of playing .mp4 videos or with [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

```
$player = $video->add('VidoPlayer_HTML5');
$player->setSource($url);
$player->js(true)
    ->_load('mediaelement-and-player.min')
    ->_css('mediaelementplayer')
    ->mediaelementplayer();
```

(p.s. is code interface looks good?)

Comment: I believe using atk4 it would take < 1h to build it from scratch :)

Comment: easy rep for someone. https://github.com/atk4/atk4-web/blob/master/page/doc/sc.php#L27 + https://github.com/atk4/atk4-web/blob/master/templates/jui/view/videoplayer.html is what I got so far :)